# Codedeploy setup error: is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to create a simple code pipeline to deploy a SAM template.
In the codedeploy I am getting the following error

> User: arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:user/iamadmin is not authorized to
> perform: iam:PassRole on resource: AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS

My understanding of this error is that the user **iamadmin** is not having permission to pass the role to the codedeploy to do what it needs to do on the user iamadmin's behalf.

To fix this I added the below policy to user **iamadmin**. However, it still gives the same error.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try with `"Resource": "*"` just check check general case. Otherwise maybe there are some SCPs on your account if its not your own that prohibit such an action.

Comment: tried it with resource:* too. still the same error

Comment: also In the policies assigned to the user iamadmin I cannot see any action which explicitly deny

Comment: Is this your own account? It could be part of AWS Org which can deny it.

Comment: yes it is own account